# sending email in CodeIgniter through gmail

Tags: codeigniter, mamp

I'm following a tutorial to send emails using gmail, however what I get is a page that just hangs and doesn't even load an error. I'm using MAMP so that may be a reason why it isnt working.

```
class Email extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();

   }

    function index(){

        $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'email',
            'smtp_pass' => 'pass'
        );

        $this->load->library('email',$config);

        $this->email->set_newline("/r/n");
        $this->email->from('email', 'George');
        $this->email->to('email');
        $this->email->subject('hey this is an email');
        $this->email->message('this is the content of the email');

        if($this->email->send()){

                echo 'Your message was sent';

        }else{

            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());

        }

    }



}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your php.ini file uncomment extension=php_openssl.dll

```
$config = Array(
            'protocol'  => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => '465',
            'smtp_user' => 'someuser@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'password',
            'mailtype'  => 'html',
            'starttls'  => true,
            'newline'   => "\r\n"
        );

    $this->load->library('email', config);
    $this->email->from('email@gmail.com', 'George');
    $this->email->to('email@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('hey this is an email');
    $this->email->message('this is the content of the email');
    $this->email->send();
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Hope this will work

Comment: i did not have that line in my php.ini, however the code you provided seemed to work. I guess I needed to add the starttls paramter.

Comment: Tried this and it worked. Narrowing it down, adding `$config['newline'] = "\r\n"` to my email config fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The line causing problems is:

```
$this->email->set_newline("/r/n");
```

Remove it and try sending the email.

Comment: no, it still hangs. Is there something I need to set in gmail?

Comment: did you enable remote SMTP in gmail?

Comment: Yes pop and imap are enabled. also, what is the difference between smtp.gmail.com and ssl://smtp.googlemail.com

Answer (score 0):

I just did this successfully myself, but through sending all values in config/email.php instead. That part shouldn't matter.

Well basicly are you trying to send through a @gmail account or your own domain? If you're trying to go through your own domain, you need to change the DNS to relevant google settings:

[Create MX Records](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=140034)

Answer (score 0):

MAMP does not ship with the openssl extension, but you can create it yourself. For details see [this](http://jaspan.com/openssl-support-php-under-mamp) tutorial

Answer (score -1):

Start by posting using the standard smtp ports and make sure that works using the config below:

function index(){

$config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 25,
            'smtp_user' => 'email',
            'smtp_pass' => 'pass'
        );

$this->load->library('email',$config);

$this->email->from('email', 'George');
        $this->email->to('email');
        $this->email->subject('hey this is an email');
        $this->email->message('this is the content of the email');

$this->email->send();
    }

Once you've tried that and it's all working have a read through this:

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/84689/