# unable to Send email using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I've a registration form and and want to send email to "To Email" and at the same time want to insert user record in db , insertion is successfull but email is not sending using codeigniter here is my code snippet from model and controller resp.
model:

```
 public function add_user()
 {
  $data=array(
    'username'=>$this->input->post('user_name'),
      'first_name' =>  $this->input->post('fname'),
      'last_name' =>  $this->input->post('lname'),
    'email'=>$this->input->post('email_address'),
    'password'=>md5($this->input->post('password'))
  );

  return  $this->db->insert('user',$data);
  //return $data;
 }
and here is controller code:

 $this->user_model->add_user();
 $this->thank();
  $config = Array(      
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'abc@gmail.com',
                'smtp_pass' => '******',
        'smtp_timeout' => '4',
        'mailtype'  => 'text', 
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );


        $this->load->library('email',$config);
        $this->email->from('mubbashir.azez@gmail.com');
        $this->email->to($data['Email']);
        $this->email->subject('test subject');
        $this->email->message('hello CI');
        $this->email->send();
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

here is view code:

```
  <label for="email_address">Your Email:</label>
  <?php echo form_error('email_address','<div class="error">', '</div>');?>
  <input type="text" id="email_address" name="email_address" value="<?php echo set_value('email_address'); ?>" />
  </p>
```

print debugger result:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: controllers/user.php

Line Number: 82

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fgets() [function.fgets]: SSL: The operation completed successfully.

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1869

220 mx.google.com ESMTP ea4sm1055346wib.7 - gsmtp 
hello: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [139.190.86.52]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 CHUNKING
from: 250 2.1.0 OK ea4sm1055346wib.7 - gsmtp
to: 555 5.5.2 Syntax error. ea4sm1055346wib.7 - gsmtp
The following SMTP error was encountered: 555 5.5.2 Syntax error. ea4sm1055346wib.7 - gsmtp 
data: 503 5.5.1 RCPT first. ea4sm1055346wib.7 - gsmtp
The following SMTP error was encountered: 503 5.5.1 RCPT first. ea4sm1055346wib.7 - gsmtp 

The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Wed, 12 Feb 2014 03:26:52 +0500
From: <mubbashir.azez@gmail.com>
Return-Path: <mubbashir.azez@gmail.com>
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?test_subject?=
Reply-To: "mubbashir.azez@gmail.com" <mubbashir.azez@gmail.com>
X-Sender: mubbashir.azez@gmail.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <52faa3ac53dcf@gmail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_52faa3ac53dd9"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_52faa3ac53dd9
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

hello CI


--B_ALT_52faa3ac53dd9
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

hello CI

--B_ALT_52faa3ac53dd9--
```

Comment: Move the debugger outside of the if statement...and check that

Comment: moved and pasted the print debugger result please advice what else to do

Comment: because you didn't define $data in controller thats why the error came and $data array generates null values

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10588040/1239506

Answer (score 0):

The return value in your model must be
    $data

and in your controller code: 
replace this

```
$this->user_model->add_user();
```

with

```
$data = $this->user_model->add_user();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this into your controller:

```
$data=array(
    'username'=>$this->input->post('user_name'),
    'first_name' =>  $this->input->post('fname'),
    'last_name' =>  $this->input->post('lname'),
    'email'=>$this->input->post('email_address'),
    'password'=>md5($this->input->post('password'))
);
```

Pass this `$data` to your model:

```
$this->user_model->add_user($data);
```

In your model also write:

```
add_user($data);
```

Then change this line also

```
$this->email->to($data['Email']);
```

to

```
$this->email->to($data['email']);
```